# Calculating event happening from percent

Tags: php, math, probability-theory

I couldn't find any answers, so I am asking here.

How can I calculate whether an event should be triggered or not based on percent?

Let me explain.

Let say an event has a 30% probability of occurring.

When I run the script (call a function) how can I know if that event falls into that 30% or not?

Basically, in the end, I have to return true or false from a function.

Hopefully, you understand what I mean.

I have my own solution, but I believe it isn't correct:

```
$evasion_percent = 30;       
$did_evasion = false;
$my_evasion_number = mt_rand(0,100);

if ($my_evasion_number <= $evasion_percent) {
  $did_evasion = true;
}

return $did_evasion;
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"I have my own solution, but i believe it isn't correct:"* - That seems to be contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine.

`$evasion_percent` will be greater than or equal to a random integer 30% of the time as there are 30/100 numbers (excluding 0) that will make your function return true.

ie. (30 desirable outcomes that make this function return true / sample space of 100) ~ 30%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get random from 1 to 100, not from 0 to 100, the rest looks fine.

```
<?php

function trigger_event($percent) {
    $did_evasion = false;
    $my_evasion_number = mt_rand(1, 100);

    if ($my_evasion_number <= $percent) {
        $did_evasion = true;
    }

    return $did_evasion;
}
```

You can also try it with large number of calls (1000, 100000 or even more) and see how part of triggered events is closed to your percentage:

```
$evasion_percent = 30;

$m = 0;
for($n = 1; $n <= 1000; $n++) {
    $m += trigger_event($evasion_percent) ? 1 : 0;
}

echo $m / $n * 100;
```